# flutter camera dispose after Camera 1 facing CAMERA_FACING_FRONT state now CAMERA_STATE_OPEN for client com.samsung.adaptivebrightnessgo API Level 2

Tags: flutter, camera

I am sorry that I am not good at English as a Korean developer.

After disposing the camera controller on the flutter camera, the log below repeats indefinitely

flutter cameraconstroller.dispose() after > console log >

##################################################
I/CameraManagerGlobal(21164): Camera 1 facing CAMERA_FACING_FRONT state now CAMERA_STATE_OPEN for client com.samsung.adaptivebrightnessgo API Level 2
I/CameraManagerGlobal(21164): Camera 1 facing CAMERA_FACING_FRONT state now CAMERA_STATE_ACTIVE for client com.samsung.adaptivebrightnessgo API Level 2
I/CameraManagerGlobal(21164): Camera 1 facing CAMERA_FACING_FRONT state now CAMERA_STATE_IDLE for client com.samsung.adaptivebrightnessgo API Level 2
I/CameraManagerGlobal(21164): Camera 1 facing CAMERA_FACING_FRONT state now CAMERA_STATE_CLOSED for client com.samsung.adaptivebrightnessgo API Level 2
I/CameraManagerGlobal(21164): Camera 1 facing CAMERA_FACING_FRONT state now CAMERA_STATE_OPEN for client com.samsung.adaptivebrightnessgo API Level 2
I/CameraManagerGlobal(21164): Camera 1 facing CAMERA_FACING_FRONT state now CAMERA_STATE_ACTIVE for client com.samsung.adaptivebrightnessgo API Level 2
I/CameraManagerGlobal(21164): Camera 1 facing CAMERA_FACING_FRONT state now CAMERA_STATE_IDLE for client com.samsung.adaptivebrightnessgo API Level 2
I/CameraManagerGlobal(21164): Camera 1 facing CAMERA_FACING_FRONT state now CAMERA_STATE_CLOSED for client com.samsung.adaptivebrightnessgo API Level 2
I/CameraManagerGlobal(21164): Camera 1 facing CAMERA_FACING_FRONT state now CAMERA_STATE_OPEN for client com.samsung.adaptivebrightnessgo API Level 2
I/CameraManagerGlobal(21164): Camera 1 facing CAMERA_FACING_FRONT state now CAMERA_STATE_ACTIVE for client com.samsung.adaptivebrightnessgo API Level 2
I/CameraManagerGlobal(21164): Camera 1 facing CAMERA_FACING_FRONT state now CAMERA_STATE_IDLE for client com.samsung.adaptivebrightnessgo API Level 2
I/CameraManagerGlobal(21164): Camera 1 facing CAMERA_FACING_FRONT state now CAMERA_STATE_CLOSED for client com.samsung.adaptivebrightnessgo API Level 2
##################################################
the log repeats.

This log is only occurring on some devices.

When tested on a Galaxy A31 device, it occurs after camera controller dispose, and as a result, it is triggered only when the 'Brightness Optimization' option is turned on in the Galaxy A31 display setting.
If you turn off the 'Optimize Brightness' option, the log will not be output.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YgdTC.jpg)

It's happening in the basic example as well, but why does the log output indefinitely?

Can I ignore the log?

flutter version : 3.13.9

camera : 0.10.5+5

issue device : Galaxy A31(android version 12)

This question was written in Korean and translated into Papago.

Thank you for reading it.

---

Brightness Optimization on/off, cameracontroller.dispose check, other device check

Brightness Optimization on -> log repeats

Brightness Optimization off -> good

other device => good

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

this is a specific device error, that needs to be resolved by Samsung, a similar problem occurred at Samsung M21 also and M30 also , might be possible that it can be specific Samsung M series camera issue